# Как сделать, чтобы числа на кнопках увеличивались по отдельности?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку её показатель увеличивался на 1. Сейчас же при нажатии на кнопку ВСЕ показатели увеличиваются на 1

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()

tk.title("Математика. Счетчик")
canvas = Canvas(tk, width = 220, height = 580)
canvas.pack()

z1=0
z2=0
z3=0
z4=0
z5=0
z6=0
z7=0
z8=0
z9=0
z10=0
z11=0
z12=0
z13=0
z14=0
z15=0
z16=0
z17=0
z18=0
z19=0

def click_button():
    if btn1:
        global z1
        z1 += 1
        btn1Text.set("{}".format(z1))
    if btn2:
        global z2
        z2 += 1
        btn2Text.set("{}".format(z2))
    if btn3:
        global z3
        z3 += 1
        btn3Text.set("{}".format(z3))
    if btn4:
        global z4
        z4 += 1
        btn4Text.set("{}".format(z4))
    if btn5:
        global z5
        z5 += 1
        btn5Text.set("{}".format(z5))
    if btn6:
        global z6
        z6 += 1
        btn6Text.set("{}".format(z6))
    if btn7:
        global z7
        z7 += 1
        btn7Text.set("{}".format(z7))
    if btn8:
        global z8
        z8 += 1
        btn8Text.set("{}".format(z8))
    if btn9:
        global z9
        z9 += 1
        btn9Text.set("{}".format(z9))
    if btn10:
        global z10
        z10 += 1
        btn10Text.set("{}".format(z10))
    if btn11:
        global z11
        z11 += 1
        btn11Text.set("{}".format(z11))
    if btn12:
        global z12
        z12 += 1
        btn12Text.set("{}".format(z12))
    if btn13:
        global z13
        z13 += 1
        btn13Text.set("{}".format(z13))
    if btn14:
        global z14
        z14 += 1
        btn14Text.set("{}".format(z14))
    if btn15:
        global z15
        z15 += 1
        btn15Text.set("{}".format(z15))
    if btn16:
        global z16
        z16 += 1
        btn16Text.set("{}".format(z16))
    if btn17:
        global z17
        z17 += 1
        btn17Text.set("{}".format(z17))
    if btn18:
        global z18
        z18 += 1
        btn18Text.set("{}".format(z18))
    if btn19:
        global z19
        z19 += 1
        btn19Text.set("{}".format(z19))

btn1Text = StringVar()
btn1Text.set("{}".format(z1))
btn1 = Button(textvariable=btn1Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn1.place(x=200, y=8)

btn2Text = StringVar()
btn2Text.set("{}".format(z2))
btn2 = Button(textvariable=btn2Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn2.place(x=200, y=38)

btn3Text = StringVar()
btn3Text.set("{}".format(z3))
btn3 = Button(textvariable=btn3Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn3.place(x=200, y=68)

btn4Text = StringVar()
btn4Text.set("{}".format(z4))
btn4 = Button(textvariable=btn4Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn4.place(x=200, y=98)

btn5Text = StringVar()
btn5Text.set("{}".format(z5))
btn5 = Button(textvariable=btn5Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn5.place(x=200, y=128)

btn6Text = StringVar()
btn6Text.set("{}".format(z6))
btn6 = Button(textvariable=btn6Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn6.place(x=200, y=158)

btn7Text = StringVar()
btn7Text.set("{}".format(z7))
btn7 = Button(textvariable=btn7Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn7.place(x=200, y=188)

btn8Text = StringVar()
btn8Text.set("{}".format(z8))
btn8 = Button(textvariable=btn8Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn8.place(x=200, y=218)

btn9Text = StringVar()
btn9Text.set("{}".format(z9))
btn9 = Button(textvariable=btn9Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn9.place(x=200, y=248)

btn10Text = StringVar()
btn10Text.set("{}".format(z10))
btn10 = Button(textvariable=btn10Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn10.place(x=200, y=278)

btn11Text = StringVar()
btn11Text.set("{}".format(z11))
btn11 = Button(textvariable=btn11Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn11.place(x=200, y=308)

btn12Text = StringVar()
btn12Text.set("{}".format(z12))
btn12 = Button(textvariable=btn12Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn12.place(x=200, y=338)

btn13Text = StringVar()
btn13Text.set("{}".format(z13))
btn13 = Button(textvariable=btn13Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn13.place(x=200, y=368)

btn14Text = StringVar()
btn14Text.set("{}".format(z14))
btn14 = Button(textvariable=btn14Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn14.place(x=200, y=398)

btn15Text = StringVar()
btn15Text.set("{}".format(z15))
btn15 = Button(textvariable=btn15Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn15.place(x=200, y=428)

btn16Text = StringVar()
btn16Text.set("{}".format(z16))
btn16 = Button(textvariable=btn16Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn16.place(x=200, y=458)

btn17Text = StringVar()
btn17Text.set("{}".format(z17))
btn17 = Button(textvariable=btn17Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn17.place(x=200, y=488)

btn18Text = StringVar()
btn18Text.set("{}".format(z18))
btn18 = Button(textvariable=btn18Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn18.place(x=200, y=518)

btn19Text = StringVar()
btn19Text.set("{}".format(z19))
btn19 = Button(textvariable=btn19Text, background="#fff",font="16", command=click_button)
btn19.place(x=200, y=548)


canvas.create_text(100,25,text="1 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,37,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,55,text="2 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,67,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,85,text="3 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,97,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,115,text="4 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,127,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,145,text="5 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,157,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,175,text="6 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,187,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,205,text="7 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,217,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,235,text="8 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,247,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,265,text="9 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,277,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,295,text="10 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,307,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,325,text="11 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,337,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,355,text="12 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,367,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,385,text="13 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,397,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,415,text="14 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,427,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,445,text="15 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,457,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,475,text="16 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,487,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,505,text="17 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,517,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,535,text="18 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,547,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,565,text="19 задание",font=('Times', 25))
canvas.create_text(100,577,text="-----------------------",font=('Times', 25))


tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Повторяющийся код нужно оборачивать в функции и тогда с ним будет просто работать через циклы

А ваше условие `if btn*:` в `click_button` всегда срабатывало, потому что в тех переменных значения явно можно было представить как `True`

Пример:

```
from tkinter import *

def on_click_button(btn_text: StringVar):
    value = int(btn_text.get())
    btn_text.set(f'{value + 1}')

def add_button(x: int, y: int) -> (Button, StringVar):
    btn_text = StringVar()
    btn_text.set("0")
    btn = Button(
        textvariable=btn_text, background="#fff", font="16",
        command=lambda: on_click_button(btn_text)
    )
    btn.place(x=x, y=y)

    return btn, btn_text

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Математика. Счетчик")
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=220, height=580)
canvas.pack()

button_start_y = 8
label_start_y = 25

for i in range(19):
    y = button_start_y + i * 30
    add_button(200, y)

    y = label_start_y + i * 30
    canvas.create_text(100, y, text=f"{i+1} задание", font=('Times', 25))
    canvas.create_text(100, y+12, text="-----------------------", font=('Times', 25))

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`if btn*:` проверяет совсем не то, что вы думаете. Это не проверяет, была ли нажата кнопка `btn*`, а проверяет, не является значение переменной `btn*` равным 0, `False` или `None`. Очевидно, что виджет кнопки не является ни одним из перечисленных трёх. Поэтому проверка даёт положительный результат во всех случаях, что приводит к увеличению всех значений.